# standard library STL in c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Can someone explain the below code?

```
vector<int> *vpoint =  new vector();
```

from what little i know, vector vpoint creates a vecor of type int, vpoint being its name. Then why do we need the above type of code?

And do we use the arrow operator -> with the the former code and use the dot operator with the latter code. Am i right. can someone explain in detail.

Is this something got to do with pointers?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: *"Then why do we need the above type of code? "* You very, very likely don't.

Comment: I don't think it'll compile. And what do you mean by "the former code" and "the latter code"? I see only one code example.

Comment: former code: 
     vector<int> *vpoint =  new vector();
latter code:
     vector<int> vpoint;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'r original code will not compile. However, answering your question, code (with fixed compilation error):

```
vector<int>* vpoint = new vector<int>;
```

Simply creates an object of std::vector class on the heap, and assigns an address of this object to `vpoint` variable.